# Meaning of "Minting an NFT" and OpenSea.io question

Tags: ethereum, nft, opensea

I have some questions regarding NFT and hope someone can clarify it for me:

Here are what I have done so far: I've successfully run through the whole process of

- Uploading an image to IPFS,
- Deployed a ERC1155 contract in remix,
- Mint an NFT and
- Successfully showed it in opensea.io

Here are my questions:

- What does it truly mean by "Minting an NFT"?  As far as I know, does it mean I create a token (NFT) that represents that uploaded image?

  - What is the role of "Minting an NFT"?
- What are the differences between "Minting an NFT using smart contract" vs "Uploading an image to opensea.io and sell it"?

  - It seems to me that they are the same.  When I mint an NFT using smart contract, opensea.io will create a new collection for me with that contract, and the result is the same when I create a collection manually and upload an image to sell.
- When I create an image and upload to IPFS, I also tried manually creating a metadata.json file to describe that file and upload it to my Google drive, which is accessible via URL.
  Then when I run the smart contract, I use that meta file link as a parameter to mint an NFT.

  - My question is: the whole process actually did not mention "opensea.io", why opensea.io knows that I am running a smart contract and create a collection for me? '

Hope someone can help clarify that for me.

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

> *What does it truly mean by "Minting an NFT"? As far as I know, does it mean I create a token (NFT) that represents that uploaded image?*

Correct. Minting a token is a term used for creating the token.

> *What are the differences between "Minting an NFT using smart contract" vs "Uploading an image to opensea.io and sell it"?*

When you upload an image to OpenSea a create a new sell order, they can currently do one of two things depending on the options you chose:

1. Mint a token in their own collection contract right away

   OR
2. Mint a token in their own collection contract when the sale is successful

> *why opensea.io knows that I am running a smart contract and create a collection for me?*

They are listening to `Transfer()` events on collection addresses registered in their system. Or query the historic events when you add the address later.

When the event is emitted, they can create a record in their own database pointing to your token in your collection contract, effectively creating an OpenSea collection page (not a collection contract) and filling it with your token details.